# how to set character encoding while creating tables using spring boot entity

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am designing my database tables using spring JPA more specifically using entity classes in spring boot. But it creates tables with collation as "latin_swedish-ci" and I want to create tables with CHARACTER SET as "utf8" & COLLATE as "utf8_general_ci"

I have set support for CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci in my application.properties 
Now I want to create my database tables with above said collation and character encoding using spring-boot entity classes

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/echarak?useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    private Long item_id;

    private String title;
    private Date creationdate;
    private Date expirydate;
    private String type;
}
```